# How to store and use inherited roles in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, security, inheritance, roles

I am trying to implement roles within my Symfony3 application.

I am having difficulty with inherited roles. I am saving the role for each user to the role column in the user table. I am not saving the inherited roles to the database.

The getRoles() function in my User entity returns the role from the role column, this does not retrieve the inherited roles.

How can I ensure that the getRoles() also returns the inherited roles in an elegant manner? I have attempted the following:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    // ensure the inherited roles from role heirarchy are added accordingly
    switch ($roles[0]){
        case 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN':
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_AGENCY_ADMIN';
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_CLIENT_ADMIN';
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
            break;
        case 'ROLE_AGENCY_ADMIN':
        case 'ROLE_CLIENT_ADMIN':
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
            break;
    }

    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

This works as expected but I have a feeling there is a better alternative. The security profiler tells me the following:
[image]

So I have the inherited roles in the roles section too, it doesn't seem right to me. If the security profiler knows about the inherited roles then I should be able to access that info too rather than mashing it together myself?

I've been trawling through SO to find a suitable solution but have been stumped so far.

Sincerely appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 2):

you can create new roles.yml file where you you'll define new role_hierarchy:

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:

        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:
            - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
            - ROLE_VIEW_HOME_OVERVIEW
            - ROLE_ADMIN

        ROLE_ADMIN:

            - ROLE_VIEW_HOME_OVERVIEW
            - ROLE_VIEW_CALENDAR_OVERVIEW
            - ROLE_VIEW_ADMIN_OVERVIEW_L .......
```

don't forgot to add it to your config.yml file

```
imports:
        - { resource: roles.yml }
```

and now you can check directly in your controller:

```
  if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_VIEW_HOME_OVERVIEW')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }
```

Comment: How can I make the check in form builder class?

Comment: it's the same idea but instead to throw Exception add your new field: ` if ($this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_XXXXX')) {
                $form->add('name', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'xxxxx'
                ));
            }`

Comment: I get a 'Notice: Undefined property:' for container when I try to check the role using your suggestion.